# How to change order of a grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr, panel

the df below has the similar structure as my original data. What I want to accomplish here is to group the data by "id", take the average profit of those groups and then reorder the groups based on their averages.

```
>mydata <- structure(list(id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "C", "D", "D"), year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2000L, 2002L, 2003L, 2000L, 2001L
), sales = c(2000L, 2050L, 2100L, 2150L, 2200L, 2250L, 2300L, 
2350L, 2400L, 2500L, 2550L, 2600L, 2650L), profit = c(200L, 245L, 
290L, 335L, 380L, 425L, 470L, 515L, 560L, 650L, 695L, 740L, 785L
)), .Names = c("id", "year", "sales", "profit"), row.names = c(NA, 
13L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
> mydata
   id year sales profit
1   A 2000  2000    200
2   A 2001  2050    245
3   A 2002  2100    290
4   A 2003  2150    335
5   B 2000  2200    380
6   B 2001  2250    425
7   B 2002  2300    470
8   B 2003  2350    515
9   C 2000  2400    560
10  C 2002  2500    650
11  C 2003  2550    695
12  D 2000  2600    740
13  D 2001  2650    785
```

## group the data by "id" and calculate the mean for each group

```
 group_mean=mydata%>%group_by(id)%>%summarise(m=mean(profit))%>%arrange(desc(m))
> group_mean
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     id     m
  <chr> <dbl>
1     D 762.5
2     C 635.0
3     B 447.5
4     A 267.5
```

Notice that in the original data the order of the groups is first "A", second "B" third "C" and so on. But group averages in a descending order show that "D" has the largest value, then "C" has the second largest and then comes "B" and finally "A" goes last. This is the order in which I wish to put my original data, resulting df appears as below.

```
 > newdata
   id year sales profit
1   D 2000  2600    740
2   D 2001  2650    785
3   C 2000  2400    560
4   C 2002  2500    650
5   C 2003  2550    695
6   B 2000  2200    380
7   B 2001  2250    425
8   B 2002  2300    470
9   B 2003  2350    515
10  A 2000  2000    200
11  A 2001  2050    245
12  A 2002  2100    290
13  A 2003  2150    335
```

You see, ordering within a group stays the same, what needs to change is the order of groups. Another question, how can I accomplish similar group wise reordering  based on sales numbers of the year, 2000. 
Thank you for your time and answer in advance, and I would really appreciate if the answer is a little simpler as I am new to R.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `id` to have a specific order, turn it into a factor where the levels are in that order. The `reorder` function is very handy for this. Then sorting by the `id` column will produce the order you want.

For your case:

```
mydata %>%
  mutate(id = factor(id),
         id = reorder(id, -profit, FUN = mean)) %>%
  arrange(id)
#    id year sales profit
# 1   D 2000  2600    740
# 2   D 2001  2650    785
# 3   C 2000  2400    560
# 4   C 2002  2500    650
# 5   C 2003  2550    695
# 6   B 2000  2200    380
# 7   B 2001  2250    425
# 8   B 2002  2300    470
# 9   B 2003  2350    515
# 10  A 2000  2000    200
# 11  A 2001  2050    245
# 12  A 2002  2100    290
# 13  A 2003  2150    335
```

It's nice to actually encode the order into the levels of the factor because it will be the default order for plots.

---

To get an order based on sales in the year 2000, I would get that order and then explicitly apply it:

```
ord_2000 = mydata %>% filter(year == 2000) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(sales = mean(sales)) %>%
  arrange(-sales) %>% pull(id)

mydata = mutate(mydata, id = factor(id, levels = ord_2000))
```

Alternately, you could still use `reorder`, but first sort the data by year so that 2000 is first, and then instead of using `mean` for the reordering function, use `head` and just pull the top record:

```
mydata %>% arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(id = factor(id),
         reorder(id, -sales, FUN = head, 1)) %>%
  arrange(id)
```

Comment: Works like a charm thanks! How can I do a similar reordering based on sales numbers of year 2000?

Comment: would you please provide another line of code for the part  "ord_2000" it  does not seem to give what I need.

Comment: Make sure your `dplyr` is up-to-date. `pull` is a relatively new addition. The line I provided works fine on your test data.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough about what I need. No need to calculate  mean sales, I need the group orders to be based on sales number of 2000 alone.  in this case ordering of "id" would be like c( "D","D","C","C","C","B","B","B","B","A","A","A","A" from largest sales in year 2000 to the smallest

Comment: The code works fine with or without the mean, but feel free to delete the `group_by` and `summarize()` calls if you want. Leaving it in will make it so the code works whether or not you have one or many observations in the year 2000 (per id). Taking it out will mean the code will not work if you have more than one year 2000 point per id. I didn't want to make assumptions about your data. I'm going to leave my answer as-is because it is more general.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is:

```
group_mean=mydata%>%group_by(id)%>%
                    summarise(m=mean(profit))%>%
                    arrange(desc(m)) %>% as.data.frame()   


mydata %>% mutate(id=factor(id,levels = group_mean$id)) %>%
           arrange(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential base R solution

```
specific_order <- LETTERS[4:1]
mydata[unlist(sapply(specific_order, function(i) which(i == mydata$id))), ]    

# id year sales profit
# 12  D 2000  2600    740
# 13  D 2001  2650    785
# 9   C 2000  2400    560
# 10  C 2002  2500    650
# 11  C 2003  2550    695
# 5   B 2000  2200    380
# 6   B 2001  2250    425
# 7   B 2002  2300    470
# 8   B 2003  2350    515
# 1   A 2000  2000    200
# 2   A 2001  2050    245
# 3   A 2002  2100    290
# 4   A 2003  2150    335
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem :

```
# If you want to sort in different way
arrange(mydata,desc(id),desc(sales))
# If you want to keep year == 2000 and sort your data : 
arrange(mydata[mydata$year == 2000,],desc(id),desc(sales))
```

Otherwise, can you provide an example of expected output ?

Comment: I cant seem to post df structure properly it shows up like regular text

Comment: newest
# A tibble: 16 x 3
       id  year     sales
   <fctr> <int>     <dbl>
 1      A  2000 163.40165
 2      A  2001 112.59313
 3      A  2002  91.59946
 4      A  2003 131.95467
 5      B  2000  74.47537
 6      B  2001 111.17791
 7      B  2002 165.95843
 8      B  2003 128.67058
 9      C  2000 101.53864
10      C  2001  73.85365
11      C  2002 203.94043
12      C  2003  79.04265
13      D  2000  25.65043
14      D  2001 119.47931
15      D  2002  45.00866
16      D  2003  87.11828

Comment: I'll try to explain it verbally. when you filter like >newest_data%>% filter(year==2000)%>%arrange (sales),  the result is this table                                        A tibble: 4 x 3
      id  year     sales
  <fctr> <int>     <dbl>
1      D  2000  25.65043
2      B  2000  74.47537
3      C  2000 101.53864
4      A  2000 163.40165    "D" goes first because it has the largest sales value in year 2000 and similarly "A" goes last bc it has the smalles. Now, what I need is df is reordered so "D"s go first then "B"s, then "C"s, finally "A"s, in accordance with 2000 sales number ordering

Answer (score 0):

To order the mean by group, change the variable to arrange from 'm' to 'id'

```
mydata %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(m = mean(profit)) %>%
  arrange(id)
```

To reorder your original data:

```
mydata %>%
  arrange(desc(id))
```

Comment: This works bc "as_tibble()  in the code. bc I have tried reordering after grouping data and failed everytime.